# How does "a month ago" and "the past month" in the below article differ?

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context

> "A month ago...More than 750,000 coronavirus cases were tallied
> worldwide in a single day... But the past month... New cases have
> declined to half their peak globally..."
>
> (New York Times online
> Feb.23.2021)

"*A month ago*" should be January 23, but I wonder if "*the past month*" in this sentence means January (a dictionary indicates that "*past*" means "*just ended*"). How should I understand?

Comment: _A month ago_ refers to _a single day_, as you say. _The past month_ is the whole time between then and now.

Comment: It's the basic distinction between a **length** of time, with starting or ending point or both, versus a **point** in time. _A month ago_ is punctual, so it refers to some point in the past. _The past month_ is durative, so it refers to an entire length of time, starting from the point _a month ago_, and stretching until _now_.

Comment: Thank you for quick comments. I should have check up firstly the definition of "past" on Collins English Dictionary adj. 3 which reads as "denoting a specific unit of time that immediately precedes the present one: the past month." Thank you anyway for all the help.